# Adding data (pushing pair to list of pairs) to nodes in AVL tree is not working as I expect it to

Tags: c++, list, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, std-pair

I need to read words from a text file and store their frequency of occurrence, their location in the document and the name of the document they appeared in. This needs to be stored in an AVL tree with the word as the key. I have some of it working but we are required to store the location and name of document as a pair. This is the part I am having issues with. I spent a few hours trying different things and I can't figure out why its doing what it is. Basically it seems to work kinda for the first few words in the text file but every new word it reads it adds the previous words location and document pairs onto the new word. Sorry for my messy code and poor explanation I am still new. Here is a screenshot of what my output is.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/503TN.png

main.cpp code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "AVL_ADT.h"

struct DATA
{
    string key;
    int info;
    list<pair<string, int> > index;
    bool operator<(const DATA& d) const {
        return info < d.info;
    }

};

string trim(string input) {
    stringstream ss;
    for (int x = 0; x < (int) input.size(); x++) {
        if (isalpha(input[x])) {
            ss << input[x];
        }
    }
    if (ss.str().length() > 0)
        return ss.str();
    else
        return "";
}

priority_queue<DATA> dataQueue;

void addQueue(DATA ss) {
    dataQueue.push(ss);
}

void print(DATA ss) {
    cout << ss.key <<  "," << ss.info << endl;
    list<pair<string, int> > :: iterator it;
    for(it = ss.index.begin(); it != ss.index.end(); it++){
        cout << it->first << ",";
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    AvlTree<DATA, string> tree;
    if(tree.AVL_Empty())
        cout << "Empty tree."<< endl;

    string documentName;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("testfile.txt");
    string word;
    int location = 1;
    documentName = "testfile.txt";

    DATA newItem;

    while(file>>word){
        word = trim(word);
        newItem.key = word;
        newItem.info = 1;
        if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(word, newItem)) {
            tree.AVL_Delete(word);
            newItem.info++;
            newItem.index.push_front(make_pair(documentName, location));
            tree.AVL_Insert(newItem);
        }
        else {
        newItem.index.push_front(make_pair(documentName, location));
        tree.AVL_Insert(newItem);
        }
        location ++;
    }
    file.close();

    tree.AVL_Print();

    cout<<endl;

    tree.AVL_Traverse(addQueue);

    while (!dataQueue.empty()) {
        DATA d = dataQueue.top();
        print(d);
        dataQueue.pop();
    }

return 0;

}
```

Here is the header file if it helps.

```
//  ==================== MACROS ====================
#define LH +1     // Left High
#define EH  0     // Even High
#define RH -1     // Right High

//  NODE Definitions
template <class TYPE>
struct NODE
    {
     TYPE    data;
     NODE   *left;
     NODE   *right;
     int     bal;
    } ; // NODE

// Class Declaration
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
class AvlTree
    {
     private:
        int          count;
        NODE<TYPE>  *tree;

        NODE<TYPE> *_insert          (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr,
                                      bool&       taller);

        NODE<TYPE>  *leftBalance     (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      bool&        taller);

        NODE<TYPE>  *rotateLeft      (NODE<TYPE>  *root);
        NODE<TYPE>  *rightBalance    (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      bool&        taller);
        NODE<TYPE>  *rotateRight     (NODE<TYPE>  *root);
        NODE<TYPE> *_delete          (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      KTYPE        dltKey,
                                      bool&        shorter,
                                      bool&        success);

        NODE<TYPE>  *dltLeftBalance  (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      bool&        smaller);
        NODE<TYPE>  *dltRightBalance (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                                      bool&        shorter);
        NODE<TYPE> *_retrieve        (KTYPE        key,
                                      NODE<TYPE>  *root);
        NODE<TYPE> *_update          (KTYPE        key,
                                      NODE<TYPE>  *root);

        void  _traversal  (void (*process)(TYPE dataProc),
                                  NODE<TYPE>    *root);

        void  _destroyAVL (NODE<TYPE>  *root);

//      The following function is used for debugging.
        void  _print      (NODE<TYPE> *root, int   level);

     public:
              AvlTree (void);
             ~AvlTree  (void);
        bool  AVL_Insert   (TYPE   dataIn);
        bool  AVL_Delete   (KTYPE  dltKey);
        bool  AVL_Retrieve (KTYPE  key,     TYPE& dataOut);
        bool  AVL_Update   (KTYPE key, TYPE dataIn);
        void  AVL_Traverse (void (*process)(TYPE  dataProc)); //in-order

        bool  AVL_Empty    (void);
        bool  AVL_Full     (void);
        int   AVL_Count    (void);

//      The following function is used for debugging.
        void  AVL_Print    (void);
    } ; // class AvlTree

/*  =================== Constructor ===================
    Initializes private data.
       Pre     class is being defined
       Post    private data initialized
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> ::  AvlTree (void)
{
//  Statements
    tree    = NULL;
    count   = 0;
}   //  Constructor

/*  ==================== AVL_Insert ====================
    This function inserts new data into the tree.
       Pre    dataIn contains data to be inserted
       Post   data have been inserted or memory overflow
       Return success (true) or overflow (false)
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> :: AVL_Insert (TYPE dataIn)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr;
    bool         taller;

//  Statements
    if (!(newPtr = new NODE<TYPE>))
       return false;
    newPtr->bal    = EH;
    newPtr->right  = NULL;
    newPtr->left   = NULL;
    newPtr->data   = dataIn;

    tree = _insert(tree, newPtr, taller);
    count++;
    return true;
}   //  Avl_Insert

/*  ======================= _insert =======================
    This function uses recursion to insert the new data into
    a leaf node in the AVL tree.
       Pre    application has called AVL_Insert, which passes
              root and data pointers
       Post   data have been inserted
       Return pointer to [potentially] new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
         ::  _insert (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                      NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr,
                      bool&        taller)
{
//  Statements
    if (!root)
    {
        root    = newPtr;
        taller  = true;
        return  root;
    } //  if NULL tree

    if (newPtr->data.key < root->data.key)
       {
        root->left = _insert(root->left,
                             newPtr,
                             taller);
        if (taller)
           //  Left subtree is taller
           switch (root->bal)
              {
               case LH: // Was left high--rotate
                        root = leftBalance (root, taller);
                        break;

               case EH: // Was balanced--now LH
                        root->bal = LH;
                        break;

               case RH: // Was right high--now EH
                        root->bal = EH;
                        taller    = false;
                        break;
              } // switch
       } //  new < node
    else
       //  new data >= root data
       {
        root->right = _insert (root->right,
                               newPtr,
                               taller);
        if (taller)
           // Right subtree is taller
           switch (root->bal)
               {
                case LH: // Was left high--now EH
                         root->bal = EH;
                         taller    = false;
                         break;

                case EH: // Was balanced--now RH
                         root->bal = RH;
                         break;

                case RH: // Was right high--rotate
                         root = rightBalance (root, taller);
                         break;
               } //  switch
       } //  else new data >= root data
    return root;
}   //  _insert

/*  ===================== leftBalance =====================
    The tree is out of balance to the left. This function
    rotates the tree to the right.
       Pre     the tree is left high
       Post    balance restored
       Returns potentially new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>  *AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
         :: leftBalance (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                         bool&        taller)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *rightTree;
    NODE<TYPE>  *leftTree;

//  Statements
    leftTree = root->left;
    switch (leftTree->bal)
       {
        case LH: // Left High--Rotate Right
                    root->bal     = EH;
                    leftTree->bal = EH;

                 // Rotate Right
                    root     = rotateRight (root);
                    taller   = false;
                 break;
        case EH: // This is an error
                    cout <<"\n\a\aError in leftBalance\n";
                    exit (100);
        case RH: // Right High - Requires double rotation:
                 // first left, then right
                    rightTree = leftTree->right;
                    switch (rightTree->bal)
                       {
                        case LH: root->bal     = RH;
                                 leftTree->bal = EH;
                                 break;
                        case EH: root->bal     = EH;
                                 leftTree->bal = EH;
                                 break;
                        case RH: root->bal     = EH;
                                 leftTree->bal = LH;
                                 break;
                       } //  switch rightTree

                    rightTree->bal = EH;
                    //  Rotate Left
                    root->left = rotateLeft (leftTree);

                    // Rotate Right
                    root    = rotateRight (root);
                    taller  = false;
       } // switch leftTree
    return root;
}   // leftBalance

/*  ===================== rotateLeft ======================
    This function exchanges pointers so as to rotate the
    tree to the left.
       Pre  root points to tree to be rotated
       Post NODE rotated and new root returned
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
          :: rotateLeft (NODE<TYPE>  *root)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *tempPtr;

//  Statements
    tempPtr        = root->right;
    root->right    = tempPtr->left;
    tempPtr->left  = root;

    return tempPtr;
}   //  rotateLeft

/*  ===================== rotateRight =====================
    This function exchanges pointers to rotate the tree
    to the right.
       Pre   root points to tree to be rotated
       Post  NODE rotated and new root returned
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
          :: rotateRight (NODE<TYPE> *root)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *tempPtr;

//  Statements
    tempPtr         = root->left;
    root->left      = tempPtr->right;
    tempPtr->right  = root;

    return tempPtr;
}   //  rotateRight

/*  ====================  rightBalance ===================
    The tree is out-of-balance to the right. This function
    rotates the tree to the left.
       Pre     The tree is right high
       Post    Balance restored
       Returns potentially new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>* AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
         :: rightBalance (NODE<TYPE> *root, bool& taller)
{

//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE> *rightTree;
    NODE<TYPE> *leftTree;

//  Statements
    rightTree = root->right;
    switch (rightTree->bal)
       {
        case LH: // Left High - Requires double rotation:
                 //             first right, then left
                    leftTree = rightTree-> left;

                    //  First Rotation - Left
                    switch (leftTree->bal)
                       {
                        case RH: root->bal      = LH;
                                 rightTree->bal = EH;
                                 break;

                        case EH: root->bal      = EH;
                                 rightTree->bal = EH;
                                 break;

                        case LH: root->bal      = EH;
                                 rightTree->bal = RH;
                                 break;
                       } //  switch
                    leftTree->bal = EH;

                    root->right   = rotateRight (rightTree);
                    root          = rotateLeft  (root);
                    taller        = false;
                    break;

         case EH: // Deleting from balanced node
                     root->bal = EH;
                     taller    = false;
                     break;

         case RH: // Right High - Rotate Left
                     root->bal       = EH;
                     rightTree->bal  = EH;
                     root            = rotateLeft (root);
                     taller          = false;
                     break;
        } // switch
    return root;
}   //  rightBalance

/*  ====================== AVL_Delete ======================
    This function deletes a node from the tree and rebalances
    it if necessary.
       Pre    dltKey contains key to be deleted
       Post   the node is deleted and its space recycled
              -or- an error code is returned
       Return success (true) or not found (false)
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool  AvlTree <TYPE, KTYPE> :: AVL_Delete (KTYPE  dltKey)
{
//  Local Definitions
    bool shorter;
    bool success;

    NODE<TYPE>  *newRoot;

//  Statements
    newRoot = _delete (tree, dltKey, shorter, success);
    if (success)
       {
        tree = newRoot;
        count--;
       } // if
    return success;
}   // AVL_Delete

/*  ======================== _delete =======================
    This function deletes a node from the tree and rebalances
    it if necessary.
       Pre    dltKey contains key of node to be deleted
              shorter is Boolean indicating tree is shorter
       Post   the node is deleted and its space recycled
              -or- if key not found, tree is unchanged
       Return true if deleted, false if not found
              pointer to root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
          :: _delete (NODE<TYPE> *root,
                      KTYPE       dltKey,
                      bool&       shorter,
                      bool&       success)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE> *dltPtr;
    NODE<TYPE> *exchPtr;
    NODE<TYPE> *newRoot;

//  Statements
    if (!root)
       {
        shorter = false;
        success = false;
        return NULL;
       } //  if -- base case

    if (dltKey < root->data.key)
        {
         root->left = _delete (root->left, dltKey,
                               shorter,    success);
         if (shorter)
             root   = dltRightBalance (root, shorter);
        } // if less
    else if (dltKey > root->data.key)
        {
         root->right = _delete (root->right, dltKey,
                                shorter,     success);
         if (shorter)
             root = dltLeftBalance (root, shorter);
        } //  if greater
    else
        //  Found equal node
        {
         dltPtr  = root;
         if (!root->right)
             // Only left subtree
             {
              newRoot  = root->left;
              success  = true;
              shorter  = true;
              delete (dltPtr);
              return newRoot;            //  base case
             } //  if true
         else
             if (!root->left)
                 //  Only right subtree
                 {
                  newRoot  = root->right;
                  success  = true;
                  shorter  = true;
                  delete (dltPtr);
                  return newRoot;        // base case
                } //  if
             else
                 //  Delete NODE has two subtrees
                 {
                  exchPtr = root->left;
                  while (exchPtr->right)
                      exchPtr = exchPtr->right;

                  root->data = exchPtr->data;
                  root->left = _delete (root->left,
                                        exchPtr->data.key,
                                        shorter,
                                        success);
                  if (shorter)
                      root = dltRightBalance (root, shorter);
                 } //  else

        } // equal node
    return root;
}   // _delete

  // ================== dltLeftBalance ==================
/*  The tree is out-of-balance to the left (left high)--
    rotates the tree to the right.
       Pre     The tree is left high
       Post    Balance has been restored
       Returns potentially new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
        ::  dltLeftBalance  (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                             bool&        smaller)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *rightTree;
    NODE<TYPE>  *leftTree;

//  Statements
    switch (root->bal)
        {
         case RH:  root->bal    = EH;
                   break;

         case EH:  // Delete occurred on right
                   root->bal  = LH;
                   smaller    = false;
                   break;

         case LH:  leftTree = root->left;
                   switch (leftTree->bal)
                      {
                       case LH:
                       case EH: // Rotate Single Left
                                if (leftTree->bal  == EH)
                                   {
                                    root->bal     = LH;
                                    leftTree->bal = RH;
                                    smaller       = false;
                                   } // if
                                else
                                   {
                                    root->bal     = EH;
                                    leftTree->bal = EH;
                                   } // else

                                root = rotateRight (root);
                                break;

                       case RH: //Double Rotation
                                rightTree = leftTree->right;
                                switch (rightTree->bal)
                                   {
                                    case LH: root->bal     = RH;
                                             leftTree->bal = EH;
                                             break;
                                    case EH: root->bal     = EH;
                                             leftTree->bal = EH;
                                             break;
                                    case RH: root->bal     = EH;
                                             leftTree->bal = LH;
                                             break;
                                   } //  switch
                                rightTree->bal = EH;
                                root->left     = rotateLeft (leftTree);
                                root           = rotateRight (root);
                                break;
                      } //  switch : leftTree->bal

        } //  switch : root->bal
    return root;
}   // dltLeftBalance

/*  =================== dltRightBalance ==================
    The tree is shorter after a delete on the left.
    Adjust the balance factors and rotate the tree
    to the left if necessary.
       Pre     the tree is shorter
       Post    balance factors adjusted and balance restored
       Returns potentially new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE>
         ::  dltRightBalance (NODE<TYPE>  *root,
                              bool&        shorter)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *rightTree;
    NODE<TYPE>  *leftTree;

//  Statements
    switch (root->bal)
       {
        case LH: //  Deleted Left--Now balanced
                 root->bal  = EH;
                 break;
        case EH: //  Now Right high
                 root->bal  = RH;
                 shorter    = false;
                 break;
        case RH: //  Right High - Rotate Left
                 rightTree = root->right;
                 if (rightTree->bal == LH)
                     // Double rotation required
                     {
                      leftTree  = rightTree->left;

                      switch (leftTree->bal)
                          {
                           case LH: rightTree->bal = RH;
                                    root->bal      = EH;
                                    break;
                           case EH: root->bal      = EH;
                                    rightTree->bal = EH;
                                    break;
                           case RH: root->bal      = LH;
                                    rightTree->bal = EH;
                                    break;
                          } // switch

                      leftTree->bal = EH;

                      // Rotate Right then Left
                      root->right = rotateRight (rightTree);
                      root        = rotateLeft  (root);
                     } //  if rightTree->bal == LH
                 else
                    {
                     //  Single Rotation Only
                     switch (rightTree->bal)
                        {
                         case LH:
                         case RH: root->bal      = EH;
                                  rightTree->bal = EH;
                                  break;
                         case EH: root->bal      = RH;
                                  rightTree->bal = LH;
                                  shorter        = false;
                                  break;
                        } // switch rightTree->bal
                     root = rotateLeft (root);
                    } // else
        } //  switch root bal
    return root;
}   //  dltRightBalance

/*  ==================== AVL_Retrieve ===================
    Retrieve node searches the tree for the node containing
    the requested key and returns pointer to its data.
       Pre     dataOut is variable to receive data
       Post    tree searched and data returned
       Return  true if found, false if not found
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
   ::  AVL_Retrieve  (KTYPE   key, TYPE& dataOut)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE> *node;

//  Statements
    if (!tree)
       return false;

    node    = _retrieve (key, tree);
    if (node)
       {
        dataOut = node->data;
        return true;
       } // if found
    else
       return false;
}   //  AVL_Retrieve

/*  ===================== _retrieve =====================
    Retrieve searches tree for node containing requested
    key and returns its data to the calling function.
       Pre     AVL_Retrieve called: passes key to be located
       Post    tree searched and data pointer returned
       Return  address of matching node returned
               if not found, NULL returned
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
        ::  _retrieve (KTYPE       key,
                       NODE<TYPE> *root)
{
//  Statements
    if (root)
        {
         if (key < root->data.key)
             return _retrieve (key, root->left);
         else if (key > root->data.key)
             return _retrieve (key, root->right);
         else
             // Found equal key
             return (root);
        } // if root
    else
        //Data not in tree
        return root;
}   //  _retrieve

/*  ==================== AVL_Update ===================
    Update node searches the tree for the node containing
    the requested key and updates with new data.
       Pre     dataIn is new data
       Post    tree searched and node updated
       Return  true if found, false if not found
*/
/*
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
   ::  AVL_Update  (KTYPE   key, TYPE dataIn)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE> *node;

//  Statements
    if (!tree)
       return false;

    node    = _update (key, tree);
    if (node)
       {
        node->data = dataIn;
        return true;
       } // if found
    else
       return false;
}   //  AVL_Retrieve*/

/*  ===================== _update =====================
    Retrieve searches tree for node containing requested
    key and returns its data to the calling function.
       Pre     AVL_Retrieve called: passes key to be located
       Post    tree searched and data pointer returned
       Return  address of matching node returned
               if not found, NULL returned
*/

/*template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
        ::  _update (KTYPE       key,
                       NODE<TYPE> *root)
{
//  Statements
    if (root)
        {
         if (key < root->data.key)
             return _update (key, root->left);
         else if (key > root->data.key)
             return _update (key, root->right);
         else
             // Found equal key
             return (root);
        } // if root
    else
        //Data not in tree
        return root;
}   //  _retrieve*/

/*  ==================== AVL_Traverse ====================
    Process tree using inorder traversal.
       Pre   process used to "visit" nodes during traversal
       Post  all nodes processed in LNR (inorder) sequence
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
  ::  AVL_Traverse (void (*process)(TYPE dataProc))
{
//  Statements
    _traversal (process, tree);
    return;
}   // end AVL_Traverse

/*  ===================== _traversal =====================
    Traverse tree using inorder traversal. To process a
    node, we use the function passed when traversal is called.
       Pre   tree has been created (may be null)
       Post  all nodes processed
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
  ::  _traversal (void(*process)(TYPE dataproc),
                  NODE<TYPE> *root)
{
//  Statements
    if (root)
       {
        _traversal  (process, root->left);
        process     (root->data);
        _traversal  (process, root->right);
       } //  if
    return;
}   //  _traversal

/*  =================== AVL_Empty ==================
    Returns true if tree is empty, false if any data.
       Pre      tree has been created; may be null
       Returns  true if tree empty, false if any data
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> ::  AVL_Empty (void)
{
//  Statements
    return (count == 0);
}   //  AVL_Empty

/*  =================== AVL_Full ===================
    If there is no room for another node, returns true.
       Pre      tree has been created
       Returns  true if no room, false if room
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> ::  AVL_Full (void)
{
//  Local Definitions
    NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr;

//  Statements
    newPtr = new NODE<TYPE>;
    if (newPtr)
       {
        delete  newPtr;
        return false;
       } // if
    else
       return true;
}   //  AVL_Full

/*  =================== AVL_Count ===================
    Returns number of nodes in tree.
       Pre     tree has been created
       Returns tree count
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
int  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> ::  AVL_Count (void)
{
//  Statements
    return (count);
}   //  AVL_Count

/*  =================== Destructor ===================
    Deletes all data in tree and recycles memory.
    The nodes are deleted by calling a recursive
    function to traverse the tree in inorder sequence.
       Pre      tree is a pointer to a valid tree
       Post     all data have been deleted
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> :: ~AvlTree  (void)
{
//  Statements
    if (tree)
       _destroyAVL (tree);
}   // Destructor

/*  =================== _destroyAVL ===================
    Deletes all data in tree and recycles memory.
    The nodes are deleted by calling a recursive
    function to traverse the tree in postorder sequence.
       Pre   tree is being destroyed
       Post  all data have been deleted
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
  ::  _destroyAVL (NODE<TYPE>  *root)
{
//  Statements
    if (root)
       {
        _destroyAVL (root->left);
        _destroyAVL (root->right);
        delete root;
       } // if
    return;
}   //  _destroyAVL

/*  ============================= AVL_Print =============================
    This function prints the AVL tree by calling a recursive inorder
    traversal. NOTE: THIS IS NOT AN APPLICATION ADT FUNCTION. IT IS
    USED ONLY FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES.

    To correctly visualize the tree when turned sideways, the actual
    traversal is RNL.
    Pre  Tree must be initialized. Null tree is OK.
         Level is node level: root == 0
    Post Tree has been printed.
*/
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> :: AVL_Print (void)
{
/*  statements */
    _print (tree, 0);
    return;
}   /* AVL_PRINT */

/*  ============================= _print =============================
    This function is not a part of the ADT. It is included to verify
    that the tree has been properly built by printing out the tree
    structure.
*/

/*  This function uses recursion to print the tree. At each level, the
    level number is printed along with the node contents (an integer).
    Pre     root is the root of a tree or subtree
            level is the level of the tree: tree root is 0
    Post    Tree has been printed.
*/
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void  AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> ::  _print (NODE<TYPE> *root,
                                       int         level)
{
 /* Local Definitions */
    int i;

 /* Statements */
    if (root)
        {
         _print ( root->right, level + 1 );

         cout << "bal "     << setw(3) << root->bal
              << ": Level " << setw(3) << level;

         for (i = 0; i <= level; i++ )
            cout << "....";
         cout << setw(3) << root->data.key;
         if (root->bal == LH)
            cout << " (LH)\n";
         else if (root->bal == RH)
            cout << " (RH)\n";
         else
            cout << " (EH)\n";

         _print ( root->left, level + 1 );
        } /* if */

 } /* AVL_Print */
```

Comment: [What is a debugger, and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to understand your problem and identify what was correct (the AVL part) and what was untested (in fact `main` code).

The problem is that `newItem` is declared outside of the `while` loop, so it keeps its values between iterations, specificaly the `index` member. So for a trivial fix, just declare it inside the loop:

```
...
while(file>>word){
    DATA newItem;
    word = trim(word);
    newItem.key = word;
    ...
```

That will be enough for all its members to be default initialized which will ensure an emply list at each iteration.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I thought I understood the differences between declaring a varaible inside and outside loops but I guess not. I still am having some trouble wrapping my head around why declaring it outside the loop only affects the index member. The frequency counting works with it outside so I thought it was some other issue. If you don't mind can you break it down for me so I can understand better.

Comment: @roxas0010: You explicitely set the values of the `key` and `info` members inside the loop, so they cannot retain the previous value. Alternatively, you could still declare the `newItem` variable outside the loop, provided you explicitely reset the content of its `index` member with `newItem.index.clear()`.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking and looking more carefully at the code I realised exactly why it was happening. Thanks for your explanation anyway. And thanks again for solving my original issue. You were very helpful :)